# Kotlin: Join 2 tables based on a differently named attribute

Tags: kotlin, join

In Kotlin if I wanted to join 2 tables (for example: Invoice and Payment) based on a common attribute (for example: paymentId) I would do something like this:

```
val joinPayment = it.join<Invoice, Payment>("paymentId")
```

what do I need to do to join the tables if the name of the attribute is different in each table? (For example: paymentId inside the Invoice table and id inside the Payment table)

Comment: I expect a new table that has all the columns from Invoice and all the columns from Payment. In this table a row is created when the values from the columns paymentId and id are equal.

Answer (score 0):

Well, this is the most generic solution you can get I think.

```
fun <T, K, V, M> List<T>.join(
    other: List<K>,
    keySelectorT: (T) -> V,
    keySelectorK: (K) -> V,
    mergingFunction: (T, K) -> M
): List<M> {
    val result = mutableListOf<M>()
    val associatedT = associateBy(keySelectorT)
    val associatedK = other.associateBy(keySelectorK)
    associatedT.forEach { (key,value) ->
        associatedK[key]?.let { kValue -> result.add(mergingFunction(value, kValue )) }
    }
    return result
}
```

You can't access a member of a class by using its name(unless you would want to use reflection and for that, it's insane overkill) + the names wouldn't match anyway.

Since you did not provide what any of the data looks like I will try to show it on an example:

```
data class Foo(val name: String, val age: Int)
data class Bar(val firstName: String,val  humour: String)
data class FooBar(val name: String, val age: Int, val humour: String)

val foo = listOf(Foo("John", 33), Foo("Jane", 33))
val bar = listOf(Bar("John", "dark"), Bar("Jane", "darker"))
```

Here is the usage:

```
foo.join(
    other = bar,
    keySelectorT = { fooItem: Foo -> fooItem.name },
    keySelectorK = { barItem: Bar -> barItem.firstName },
    mergingFunction = { fooItem: Foo, barItem: Bar -> FooBar(fooItem.name, fooItem.age, barItem.humour)}
)
```